# Create Custom Edit Template with Kendo Scheduler

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Is there a way to create your own Edit window with a Kendo Scheduler?  I need to be able to open my own edit window when I double click on the event in the scheduler.

Answer (score 5):

You should define an [`editable.template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#configuration-editable.template).

For example:

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h3>Edit meeting</h3>
    <p>
        <label>Title: <input name="title" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label>
    </p>
</script>
```

and the scheduler initialization as:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
    editable: {
        template: $("#editor").html()
    },
    views: [
        { type: "day" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
        {
            id: 1,
            start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
            end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
            title: "Interview"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answers above show you how to customise the content of the edit window. If you want to replace the entire window [here](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/external-editor-form) is a link to the Telerik documentation which shows how to do it.

Basically what you have to do is use the edit event of the scheduler and call .preventDefault(). After that you have to add code that uses your editor form.

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent popup editing
    var dataSource = this.dataSource;
    var event = e.event;

    if (event.isNew()) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            dataSource.add(event);
            editEvent(event);
        });
    } else {
        editEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Not so long time ago I had the same problem but the information seems hard to find so I thought I can share it here.

Answer (score 0):

var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

scheduler.addEvent({ title: "New Event", isAllDay: true });